# how to change the inner html with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html file with 2 divs,

when the jquery runs the inner html of the div d2

should change to "m" , for some reason the code doesnt work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This example calls a function which performs a calculation, and returns the result:</p>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <p id="d2"></p>
        <script>
            function myFunction(a, b) {
                return a * b;
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(4, 3);

            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $("d2").html("m"); 
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
$("d2").html("m");
```

with

```
$("#d2").html("m");
```

[ID Selector (“#id”)

Selects a single element with the given id attribute.](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 2):

In `jQuery` use `#` for `id` representation.    change `$('d2')` to `$("#d2").`

So nw your script is like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#d2").html("m");    
 });
```